# Marshalling a struct with std::string

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I try to marshal a struct to a function of my DLL. My DLL is written in C++ and accepts ansi strings.

```
// C++ signature
__declspec(dllexport) unsigned long __stdcall fn_func(struct st_Mystruct* stMystruct);

// The Structure in C++
#pragma pack(1) 

struct st_Mystruct{

    st_Mystruct()
    {
        string1 = "";
        string2 = "";
        string3 = "";
    }


    std::string string1;
    std::string string2;
    std::string string3;
};

#pragma pack() 

// C# Import
[DllImport("MyDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern uint fn_func([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct, SizeParamIndex = 1)] ref st_Mystruct stMystruct);
```

How can i declare and marshal the struct in C#?

Comment: I don't think you can. P/Invoke is only really useful for C-style functions and structures. If you need to marshall C++ calls, you'll need to use C++.NET or COM.

Comment: That is not possible, only a C++ compiler can generate the code required to create std::string objects.  You must write a C++/CLI wrapper instead.